# Regex expression to remove left over ascii hex code

Tags: r, regex

I am analysing some tweets and I have written an basic emoji to text dictionary. I use the following to convert emoji's to r-encoded unicode;

```
df$text <- iconv(df$text, from = "latin1", to = "ascii", sub = "byte")
```

After that I swap the unicode to a text string that describes the emoji, for example `<c2><ae>` becomes 'copyright'

Problem is I have a lot of emoji's that aren't in the dictionary and I need to remove the strings that represent them. I can remove the <> symbols with `"[[:punct:]]", "",` but I need to get rid of the alpha numeric characters inside the <>'s too.

I was thinking something like 
`gsub("^<", "")` 
but i'm honestly stumped on how to find the < > symbols and remove anything found between them, or how to make a regex that finds < then removes it and the next 3 characters.

Appreciate any help

example

```
 text <- ("have a <ed><a0><bd><ed><b8><80> day")
 gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", text)
```

gives "have a eda0bdedb880 day"

but I want "have a day"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a regex to match the `<` followed by characters that are not space (`[^ ]+`), ending in `>` and replace with blank (`""`)

```
gsub("\\<[^ ]+\\>\\s*", "", text, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "have a day"
```